# Httpd.conf does not work on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I've installed `Ubuntu Server` and `Apache2`.

I want to test my `httpd.conf` by adding following code:

```
<Directory />   
     Order allow,deny   
     Deny from all   
</Directory>
```

> +apache restart

It should raise `403` error while entering website, but I can browse my `index.html` normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines should deny all IPs:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

However, this is not the whole story. You need to place them in the right place. In Ubuntu, you need usually to edit the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` which contains the defined vhosts.

If you have a different configuration, you can post the complete configuration to get help.